# How can I filter content with a date that is somewhere this week by using Views?

Tags: 7, views

I am developing a project in Drupal 7, in this every content have date field by using the Date module.

I am trying to create a block by using the Views module in which I want to display content with its date field containing a date that is 'this week'.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You simply add the filter criteria to view.

- **operator type**: is greater than
- **value type**: -7 days

Answer (score 1):

Views and the various date modules are pretty slick in that you can "free form" a lot of the values:  `last week`, `this week`, `last tuesday` etc all work in the filters.  So you would select Date in the filters and then greater than, less than, etc and input what you needed in the to and or from fields.